# Changing coordinate system of QGIS layer to projection of Google Earth?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, google-earth

How do I change the coordinate value of a vector layer (13293061,-572595) to 119.413,-5.13677 (vector data & Google Earth do not match)?

If I output my data using Google Earth as background, the vector data does not match with the underlying google layer.

Printing the result to PDF also has this same problem.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that on this site, every thread should contain only a single question. If you have two questions, please ask them separately. Also, please try to find descriptive titles for your questions. You'll get more answers if people can clearly understand what you are asking for.

Comment: @syafrauf where are your values (13293061,-572595) coming from?

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, to convert a vector in QGIS you just need to right click on the layer in the TOC and select "save as...". In the dialog that will pop up you need to choose the CRS you need. Be sure that when loading the original vector this has (just check in the vector properties) the right CRS, it is not unusual to have vectors with non explicit CRS, in these cases QGIS handle the layer in different ways, depending how you configured the program in the general options, "CRS" tab.

Comment: I think that qgis works with the proj4 library for projections. In that case the proj4 string that describes the google projection is "+init=EPSG:900913". If the OP can find the proj4 string of his original data he can reproject and get this working.